# Capture only month and year (or null) - then convert that to a date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, datetime

I'm currently working with a client that has a VB.NET web application that was developed internally.  They've got everything storing to an Access database which they cannot alter or change for their own reasons.  I'm not familiar with any of these technologies, so I'm hoping you may have a solution.

The client has a date field that they are only capturing mm/yyyy or blank.  They need this information to save to a datetime field in the database.  I'm trying to work up a statement that will automatically take the date entered and convert from mm/yyyy to mm/01/yyyy if the date is provided, or 01/01/1970 if the field was left blank.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: So far, good answers - though they all look to be Access/VBA oriented.  The application itself is written in ASP.NET using VB.NET that just saves out to an Access database.   TimG's function looks pretty close to what I'd need, but I'm not sure if the syntax is correct for VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about MS Access functions DateSerial is what you are looking for.  The basic syntax is below.  If the stored value is text you will need to use the Mid function to parse the text into the year and month and you can use use a hard coded 1 for the day.

```
DateSerial ( year, month, day )
```

This function can be used in a select or update.  Additional logic will be required to provide a default value for the blank result.  Typically in Access this type of logic is done with an IIF.

Answer (score 0):

This (MSAccess/VBA) function will do what you are asking. If you pass-in a string like mm/yyyy, it will return a datetime like mm/01/yyyy.  However, if the string does not fit that pattern (or equiv), the function will return a date time of 1/1/1970, like you asked.

```
'in MSAccess:
Public Function mmyyyyToDate(mmyyyy As String) As Datetime
   If IsDate(Replace(mmyyyy, "/", "/01/")) Then
      Return CDate(Replace(mmyyyy, "/", "/01/"))
   Else
      Return #1/1/1970#
   End If
End Function
```

It would be more efficient to run it in MSAccess, but if you want to run it in VB.net instead, the syntax is different:

```
'in VB.NET
Public Function mmyyyyToDate(mmyyyy As Object, Optional defaultDate As DateTime = "1/1/1970") As DateTime
   Dim re As DateTime
   If Convert.IsDbNull(mmyyyy)
      return defaultDate
   ElseIf DateTime.TryParse(Replace(mmyyyy, "/", "/01/"), re) Then
      Return re
   Else
      Return defaultDate
   End If
End Function
```

Example of running it:

```
'MSAccess query syntax
INSERT INTO NewDateTable (NewDateColumn)
SELECT mmyyyyToDate(oldColumn) FROM OldTable
```

If you can't add a new function to the MSAccess DB, you could turn this function into an inline statement (by using an IIF), but it looks pretty ugly:

```
'MSAccess query syntax
INSERT INTO NewDateTable (NewDateColumn)
SELECT IIF(IsDate(Replace(oldColumn, "/", "/01/")), Replace(mmyyyy, "/", "/01/"), #1/1/1970#) 
FROM OldTable
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your code. rather than write a code.

Comment: I think this is on the right track - but will the same Syntax work an ASP.NET application written in VB.net?  (You mentioned it was an MSAccess/VBA function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `IIf`,`IsNull` and `CDate` functions, like so:

```
IIf(IsNull([YourDateFField]),#1/1/1970#,CDate([YourDateFField]))
```

This tests if your field is null and if yes it returns 1/1/1970, if no it will convert your date string to an actual date (e.g. CDate("04/2014") will return 4/1/2014)